# Django: Class Instance in context_processor

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to input in a base template a reference to a model class. I could do it in returning a list of models instances from context_processor but it would be more elegant to add a reference to a class.

Here is my template code:

```
{% for langue in Langue.objects.all %}
    <li><a href="{% url "ListeUEsParLangue" langue.code %}">{{ langue.label }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Here, my context_processor code :

```
def add_langue_object(request):
    from ..baobab.models import Langue
    return {'Langue': Langue}
```

My error infos : 
    AttributeError at /2016/ue/1896/

```
Manager isn't accessible via Langue instances

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://enseignements-2017.local:8000/2016/ue/1896/
Django Version:     1.9.2
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    Manager isn't accessible via Langue instances

Exception Location:     /Users/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/.virtualenvs/enseignements-2017/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py in __get__, line 250
```

I guess that in creating Context Django calls on returned class instances.

Any idea?

Thx a lot,

Comment: Provided that `baobab.models.Langue` is a model class, the code you posted shouldn't raise this error, so either `baobab.models.Langue` is not your model class _or_ there's another `Langue` in your context that is a `Langue` instance and shadows the one set in your processor.

Comment: Sorry, but tested it locally with other namings and Django raises the above exception! I can confirm that I render a **class** but inside the template I, too, get the same error...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Django template language [tries calling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups) any variables that are callable. So it is effectively trying to do `Langue().objects.all()`, which gives the exception

Personally, I disagree that it's more elegant to pass the model to the template instead of the queryset. I would prefer to do the following.

```
from ..baobab.models import Langue

def add_langues (request):
    return {'langues': Langue.objects.all()}
```

Then change your template to:

```
{% for langue in langues %}
```

Comment: Yes this is what I achevied to understand. I will choose to pass queryset. Thx !

Comment: This should be chosen as answer if it is correctly solving your problem @FrédéricHébert

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{% for langue in Langue.all %}
    <li><a href="{% url "ListeUEsParLangue" langue.code %}">{{ langue.label }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}

def add_langue_object(request):
    from ..baobab.models import Langue
    return {'Langue': Langue.objects}
```

or change Langue model to:

```
class Langue(models.Model):
    do_not_call_in_templates = True
    .....
```

Comment: This should work, but it's potentially confusing to the variable `Langue` to store `Langue.objects`.